# How to Strava oauth without a server?

Tags: c#, http, oauth-2.0, strava, strava-api-v3

I have been developing the desktop application on C#. How can I do the oauth process without running a local server?

I can't run the local server because I have a running server on the localhost from another application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible unless you perform some [manual actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880434/problem-with-access-token-in-strava-api-v3-get-all-athlete-activities/52888659#52888659).

The only solution is running multiple servers simply assigning [different ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319697/can-i-run-two-web-servers-on-the-same-computer).

Comment: Problem with that, it's requires admin privilege.